# Como posso prevenir o erro #1415 VB.NET MySQL?

Tags: sql, vb.net

Estou a fazer um trabalho escolar de uma gestão de biblioteca, cujo a minha base de dados é em MySQL e o SGBD que estou a criar é feito em VB.NET, e recentemente comecei a usar as Foreign Keys para criar relações entre tabelas, sendo assim, criei uma para a coluna **AUT_ID** da tabela **Autor** e relacionei-a com a coluna **LIV_AUT_ID** da tabela Livros.

Dentro do código que fiz em VB que elimina os dados da tabela Autor, recebo um erro ao executar tais comando:

> #1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails  (paymesomething.advertisers, CONSTRAINT advertisers_ibfk_1
> FOREIGN KEY  (advertiser_id) REFERENCES jobs (advertiser_id))

O código que tenho é este:

```
'Remover autor "Remover"
    '
    Private Sub Btn_remover_aut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_remover_aut.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Você tem a certeza de que quer eliminar o que selecionou?", "Atenção", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
            connection.Open()
            cmd = connection.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "delete from Autor where AUT_ID = @cod;"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", Txt_cod.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            connection.Close()
            atualizar_aut()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Eu gostaria de saber de que maneira posso avisar o utilizador do SGBD de que é impossível eliminar um **Autor** sendo que ele está associado a **Livros**, ou seja, **como posso prevenir de aparecer o erro #1451**.

Comment: Já usou [`try/catch/finnaly`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement)?

Comment: Entretanto consegui resolver o problema usando isso mesmo, muito obrigado de qualquer maneira.